# Objective C Method to Invoke block if not NULL, with variadic argument list

Tags: objective-c-blocks, variadic-functions

I am trying to write to a method that first checks if a block is not NULL, and if not invokes the block with `variadic` arguments. I am new to this sort of thing.

I am getting all sorts of errors with the following code:

```
-(void)invokeBlockIfNotNull:(void(^)(void))blockToInvoke withArguments:(id) firstArgument,...
{
    if(blockToInvoke != NULL)
    {
        blockToInvoke(##__VA_ARGS__);
    }
}
```

I have come across a macro that does the same thing, but I want to see how it looks in an objective c method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You can write a block that takes a va_list as its argument. I'd say it is misguided, when all you save is one if statement.

Your function *cannot* work, because the block is explicitly declared to have no arguments.

Even if you made it work with a block that takes a variable argument list, you couldn't then use it for blocks with some fixed argument list. Variable argument lists and fixed argument lists are not compatible.

Comment: how would I adjust the block declaration to take a variable number of arguments so that I can pass any block into that method. Or the whole idea is impossible?